# Javascript/jQuery Tool for drawing diagrams in html5 (canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm looking for a JS/jQuery-Tool for a web application where i can allow users to draw their own diagrams. It would be nice to have something like rectangles, arrows, text and a undo-button.

i actually found [this tool](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) but this is only for drawing and erasing.

does anyone know some tool i looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use on of these libraries:

1. [Draw2d](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/home/index.html) works across devices and browsers (check the example section)
2. [GoJs](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html)
3. [here](http://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams) you can see a little comparative about some drawing libraries

I recommend you read about the differences and scope of the libraries so you can choose the best for your application.

Answer (score 0):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram. Diagrams can be user created (interactively) or scripted programatically.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Can I create electrical diagrams with it? Any examples?

Comment: @Mark Yes. https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/qim05jtd